# Angularjs how to do IF CONTAINS in $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to know if it's possible to know if there are a char in a $scope
for example something like this but in angularJs

```
$scope.test = "Hi, How Are You?";
if($scope.test.Contains("?")) {
  return true
} else {
  return false
}
```

Comment: AngularJS is *just* a JavaScript framework, so everything that is available for strings in JavaScript is available for strings in AngularJS...

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring-in-javascript

Comment: Btw, note that you can replace the whole `if` block of your pseudocode with something like to `return $scope.test.Contains("?")`. No need to return the `true` and `false` values separately like that.

Answer (score 21):

You can just replace `Contains` with `match`:

```
if($scope.test.match("?")) {
    return true
} else {
    return false
}
```

And you can even further optimize this whole code block to just:

```
return !!$scope.test.match("?");
```

Comment: nice, i'm looking exactly like this!

Answer (score 5):

Well you can do it like this..

```
var string = "hello";
alert(string.indexOf("llo") != -1);
```

so in regards to your code above..

```
$scope.test= "HI How Are You ?";
alert($scope.test.indexOf("How") != -1); // return true;
```

Comment: I like to use `~string.indexOf("llo")` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try the codes below:

```
ng-attr-target="{{(p.link.indexOf('https://')!=-1) ? '_blank' : _self}}"
```